# System.InvalidOperationException: "Object is currently in use elsewhere."

Tags: c#, winforms, графика

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
namespace ЖИЗА
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static int[,] cellmap = new int[200,200];
        public static int test = 1;
        static Graphics g;
        static Random rnd = new Random();
        public Form1()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++)
                {
                    cellmap[i, j] = 0;
                }
            }
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static void aboba(object obj)
        {
            int x1 = rnd.Next(0, 199);
            int y1 = rnd.Next(0, 199);
            cellmap[x1, y1] = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++)
                {
                    if (cellmap[i, j] != 0)
                    {
                        **g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 3), i*2, j * 2, 2, 2);**
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        private void Form1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int num = 0;
            g = CreateGraphics();
            // создаем таймер
            TimerCallback tcb = new TimerCallback(aboba);
            System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(tcb, num, 0, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Изучаю drawing в c# winforms
Какое-то время все нормально работает, код рисует квадраты в случайных местах, но если расширить экран или просто в случайный момент времени строка `g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 3), i*2, j * 2, 2, 2);` выдается эта ошибка, что делать?

Я пока не знаю что с этим делать

Comment: Не используй `CreateGraphics()`. Используй `e.Graphics`.

Comment: На кой чёрт создаются новые таймеры в событии `Paint`? Достаточно одного-единственного таймера.

Comment: И вообще если это из другого треда, то придётся `Invoke` юзать, ну или ещё как-то в основной тред попасть. В идеале вообще не нужно ничего рисовать в отдельном треде, а нужно подготовить в этом треде данные, потом сказать `UI`, что пора перерисоваться (через `Invalidate` что ли, я уже забыл) и потом уже в событии `Paint` нормально отрисовать всё, как положено.